# Open server, Joomla Ошибка: The file Cache Storage is not supported on this platform

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, joomla, openserver

**OpenServer, JOOMLA**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне скинули исходники одного сайта, всё перекинул, бд в phpmyadmin тоже закинул, но, вот такая проблема

P.S
Доступ вроде бы выдал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверь права на запись к директориям /cache и /tmp в корне Joomla

Comment: Проверил, вроде бы выдан(Скриншот выше)

Comment: Проверь в настройках Joomla путь к папке кеша. И в плагине jsecure путь посмотри, если он там есть.

Comment: Большое спасибо! помогло

Comment: Но в плагине путь не нашёл, ошибка скорее всего тоже в неправильном пути. сайт запустился, но сверху над ним та же ошибка что на скриншоте:
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in W:\domains\site\plugins\system\jsecure\jsecure.php on line 19

Answer (score 0):

При переносе рабочих проектов на другой сервер нужно всегда очищать системный кэш, т.к. в нем могут содержаться старые директории к файлам из-за чего возникают ошибки.

Comment: `могут содержаться старые директории к файлам` — может быть "с файлами", а не "к файлам"?